# Using Group By On Hierarchial Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

We have a dataset, a random sample is shown below;

```
city|salesman_id|day|sale_qty

Chicago| 1  | 2017-01-16 | 24
Chicago| 1  | 2017-01-17 | 23
Chicago| 2  | 2017-01-16 | 20
NewYork| 1  | 2017-01-15 | 0
NewYork| 2  | 2017-01-15 | 10
NewYork| 1  | 2017-01-16 | 5
```

Here, we are certain that a given combination of `salesman_id` and  `day` is unique. For example, `salesman_id =1` and `day=2017-01-17` can't occur twice or more.

Now the question is, for each city, find average quantity sold. My first attempt was;

```
SELECT city,
       AVG(sale_qty)
FROM table
GROUP BY city
```

First approach gives the answer as;

```
  City|avg_sales

 Chicago| 22.33
 NewYork| 5
```

As an intuition, I tried another approach;

```
WITH CTE1(

SELECT city,
        salesman_id,
        SUM(sale_qty) AS total
FROM table
GROUP BY city, salesman_id)

SELECT city,
      AVG(total)
FROM CTE1
GROUP BY city
```

This gives the answer as;

```
city| avg_sales

Chicago| 33.5
NewYork| 7.5
```

I can see a difference in the answers. And I really want to understand, what is the root cause of this difference, and secondly, what factors should be carefully considered while using `Group By` clause. This will help me to avoid using `Group By` clause blindly in future. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first calculates the average sales for each city in the data.  What is the average sales in the city for an average salesperson on an average day?

The second calculates the average sales of the *total* for each salesperson within the city.  What is the average sales in the city for a salesperson *over all days*?

These are quite different.  There is no reason to expect them to even be close.

Comment: for second calculation, will it be okay to call it as average sales for a city.thats where I am getting stumbled.

Answer (score 0):

In your first construction, you computing the average sale amount in each city, regardless of salesman.  In the second, you are computing the sum *for each salesman in each city*, and then taking the average of *that* for each city.

Imagine that Salesman A makes 99 sales of $1 each and Salesman B makes 1 sale of $1.  In your first construction, the average would be $1.  In your second, Salesman A has a total of $99 and Salesman B has a total of $1, making for an average of $49.50.

The problem has nothing to do with SQL in general of Group By in particular; its the logic behind your calculation.